# redux useSelector not returning length of state in store

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am trying to get the state from my redux store and validating whether it is empty or not based on pressing a button however this isn't working as it's not returning the length using the useSelector hook. I'm new to redux and have a basic knowledge of React-Native so my approach is probably wrong I think, I could really use your help.

Here is the code

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

//Validation 
const ingridients = useSelector(state => state.addMeal.ingridients);
const method = useSelector(state => state.addMeal.method);
const nameState = useSelector(state => state.addMeal.name);

const validation = () => {
    ingridients.length === 0 && method.length === 0 && nameState.length === 0
        ?  Alert.alert("Fields are empty", "Please fill out all fields")
        : handleSubmit

}

<View>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={validation}>
        <Text style={styles.createButton}>Submit</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

I would really appreciate it from the bottom of my heart if someone could help me as to where I am going wrong with checking the length of my state in my redux store. Thank you in advance for your help!!!!!

Comment: What are `ingridients`, `method ` and `nameState`? Are they strings?

Comment: Do you want to show an alert when any one of them has 0 lengths or when all of them have 0 lengths?

Comment: nameState is a string, ingredients and methods are arrays

Comment: Yes please !! When all of them have 0 lengths I would like to show an alert.

Comment: Did you try logging the values in the `validation` function? Is `handleSubmit` a function? If so shouldn't you invoke it? `handleSubmit()`

Comment: Oh great thanks Invoking the function solved the problem thank you so much !!!!!!